# Finding derivatives and solving functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I'm very new to calculus and the wording on this question is confusing me as to what they want me to do.

Let $k(x)$ and $m(x)$ be two functions of $x$. Suppose we know that $k(-3)$ = $2$, $k'(-3)$ = $4$, $m(-3)$ = $8$, and $m'(-3)$ = $-1$. Use the rules for finding derivatives when $x$ = $-3$.

$$ \frac{d}{dx} (k(x)+m(x))$$

Comment: Are you aware that $k'$ and $\frac {\mathrm dk}{\mathrm dx}$ are the same thing?

Comment: Are you sure it's $k(x) + m(x)$ and not $k(x) \cdot m(x)$? The latter would make more sense given what's provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to compute the derivative of $k(x) + m(x)$ and evaluate the result at $x=-3$.  So, first  \begin{align}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( k(x) + m(x) \right)
    &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( k(x) \right) + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( m(x) \right) & &\text{Sum rule} \\
    &= k'(x) + m'(x) & &\text{definition of ${}'$}
\end{align}

Then, evaluating at $x=-3$, we have $k'(-3) + m'(-3) = 4 + (-1) = 3$.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. This is what they're asking: You have to find the derivative of the sum of k(x) and m(x), both two functions, at x=-3 given the information they've already given you, and also using everything else you've been taught about derivatives.

In general, if the wording on a question ever confuses you, slow down and break it up into sentences and read and slowly process each one. You are reading specifically to find any information they give you for use in solving the problem, and also what they're asking.

Note that I didn't post a solution to this problem, because your post didn't ask for one. I am willing to help though if you decide you need it.

Adam V. Nease

Answer (score 1):

I think it's telling you to solve the $\frac d{dx}(k(x)+m(x))$ which when differentiated goes to $k'(x) + m'(x)$. It then says to use $x=-3$, which goes to $k'(-3) + m'(-3)$. It is given that these values are $4 + (-1)$, and this equals $3$.